# How to call karaf console command in Java

Tags: java, shell, apache-karaf, karaf, opendaylight

If I want to execute a karaf shell command in my plugin (java), how to do it?

> ex: opendaylight-user@root> snmp4sdn:printdb

"org.apache.felix.service.command.CommandProcessor" can handle it ?

Comment: which version of Karaf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Karaf 3, you have to use the Felix Gogo services, ie the `CommandProcessor`.

From a `CommandProcessor`, you can create a `CommandSession` and then call `execute` on this session.

Two notes on this:

- In Karaf4, the service has changed - it's not dependent on Gogo anymore
- All the shell commands use an underlying osgi service. It's always better to use this service instead of creating command and "parsing the outputstream". For example, you can install a Bundle with `BundleContext.installBundle` or install a feature through the `FeaturesService`

Your command, for example, use the `org.opendaylight.snmp4sdn.ICore` service. See: [PrintDB](https://github.com/opendaylight/snmp4sdn/blob/master/plugin-shell/src/main/java/org/opendaylight/snmp4sdn/shell/PrintDB.java)