# Karaf Command Execution in java

Tags: java, apache-karaf

I want to do operation like `deploy/Active/Unistall`  maven bundle through java. How can i do it in java application ?
Any help?

Comment: You may get inspiration from following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010963/how-to-call-karaf-console-command-in-java

Comment: @gusto2 the above mension link does not work for me

Comment: Cited from the linked post: All the shell commands use an underlying osgi service....  you can install a Bundle with BundleContext.installBundle or install a feature through the FeaturesService

Comment: @gusto2  karaf command execution :  `session.execute( Charsequence comand );`
when i pass the command `list` it works. But if the command contains whitespaces like `list -t` it gives exception : command not found .. seems it break the command

Answer (score 0):

Almost every karaf component exposes it's internal components through OSGi Services and JMX MBeans, so there are several ways you can achieve what you want, like:

1. Create a bundle that references Karaf OSGi Services using Blueprint, Declarative Services or Spring; For example, if you want to control a bundle install/update/refresh through your bundle you will reference the BundleContext and [BundleService](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/e90bf7e82a3e71e5ac53aea6a836dd7a83fdf477/bundle/core/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/bundle/core/BundleService.java) interfaces.
2. Install Jolokia and Hawtio in your karaf, it will expose under REST Services several JMX MBeans which control bundles, instances, features and so on. With that you can create a java application that consumes those services. For a list of available Mbeans please refer to [Karaf Documentation](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/).
3. Create a Java application that connects to karaf via JMX and uses the JMX MBeans, as cited above.

It's up to you to choose which solution solves your problem.